# Does editing the server properties in Minecraft reset the whole world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Referring to the title, I'm new to minecraft and I'm wondering if changing the properties would reset the world? (I.E: The difficulty)

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. There's no reason why it should.

Comment: @Ginge Achievements are now called "advancements" and they do work in Creative. They always did, even when they were called "achievements".